# form validation with jquery-form-validator

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

the jquery-form-validator plugin doesn't validate..I am used jQuery 1.9.0 (the plugin is tested with that version).

html:

```
 <form id="Form" method="get" action="">
        <div class="box-1">
          <label for="name">CONTACT NAME*<br /></label>
          <label for="email">CONTACT EMAIL ADDRESS*<br /></label>
        <label for="tel">CONTACT PHONE NUMBER</label>
      </div>

      <div class="box-2">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="tel" name="tel" type="tel"/><br /><br />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEND" />
     </div>
     </form>
```

here the javascript I putted in the head tags (with script src to plugin and jquery of course):

javascript:

```
   <script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
              submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
            });
            $().ready(function() {
                $("#Form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        name: "required",
                        email: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        name: "Please enter your name",
                        email: "Please enter your email";
                    }
            }); 
    </script>
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Are you importing both your jQuery library and validation plugin properly?

Comment: to be sure I downloaded the plugin and putted aaaall the plugin files in the server folder...jquery is imported correctly cause my slideshow works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from:

```
$()
```

to

```
$(document)
```

you also need to change your `rules`:

```
rules: {
    name: { required: true },
    email: { required: true }
}
```

You also need to wrap all your code inside DOM ready. Final code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
    });

    $("#Form").validate({
        rules: {
             name: { required: true },
             email: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
             name: "Please enter your name",
             email: "Please enter your email";
        }

});
```

Comment: I tried but doesn't work also in this case...I've also tried to put the script in the body section after form closing tag :(

Comment: only a warning: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead" (in jquery 1.9.0.js line 3307)

Comment: wait an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; ...I try to fix

Comment: I solved in this way..I went in the plugin official page, I went in demo section, I copied and pasted the script of demo form and modified for my form...now it works...there was a syntax error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
rules: {
    name: { required: true },
    email: { required: true }
},
```